# WIX installer: How to provide confirmation to user after uninstall the program

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.7, uninstallation

How to show confirmation message in dialog to user for successful uninstallation using WIX installer?

Comment: Why bother? If it fails it will roll back with an error. Also, from a UX perspective telling the user when everything works is just noise.